# SwiftUI - TextField is disabled (not editable) when placed in List on macOS

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

TextField is disabled (not editable) when placed in List on macOS. When the same code is build for iOS and ran in Simulator, it works as expected.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

The code:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                // TextField is not editable when this code is ran on macOS
                TextField($text, placeholder: Text("Entry text"))
                Text("Entered text: \(text)")
            }
            // TextField is editable on both macOS as well as iOS
            TextField($text, placeholder: Text("Entry text"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the list is taking clicks to drive selection, which you're not using here. TextField becomes editable in the list on macOS only when the row in which it is housed has selection.

If you change your code to something like this

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var text: String = "Hello"
    @State private var selection: Int? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
                    TextField(self.$text)
                }
            }
            TextField($text)
        }
    }
}
```

then run the code, the first click on the cell will cause it to get selected and the second click will cause the text field to receive focus.

Comment: Searching for this, but it doesn't work for XCode 11.4 and Swift5.2. Please can you fix it?

Comment: The TextField prevents selection when clicking on the text most of the time on macOS 12.6.7 / Xcode 14.2 / Swift 5.7.2. TextField also doesn't scroll the text horizontally properly when the text length exceeds the TextField width. It seems like TextField is simply very buggy on Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by unwrapped the VStack. Try this

```
    struct ContentView : View {
     @State private var helloText: String = "Hello"
     @State private var selection: Int? = nil
     var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
                TextField(.constant(self.helloText), placeholder: Text("Entry text")).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Constant is only for previews

Answer (score -1):

Create the TextField using the following code

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var helloText: String = "Hello"
    @State private var selection: Int? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
                    TextField(.constant(self.helloText), placeholder: Text("Entry text")).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same here. Searching for this, but it doesn't work for XCode 11.4 and Swift5.2. Please can you fix it?